# Error: Cannot find module 'node-releases/data/processed/envs.json' #21988

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have issue with crreating new react app:

Upon running `npx create-react-app my-app`, i get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-releases/data/processed/envs.json'
```

any idea?

npm version: 7.20.2

node: v14.17.3